# Automatically select the correct port ttyS* in C/C++ and Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, serial-port, tty

I have a program that uses WxWidgets and C/C++ in Ubuntu and reads from a serial device to output the data if requested.
It works and the serial device is often connected to ttyS4.
The problem is that, sometimes, if I reboot the system, the devices can be connected to ttyS1 or ttyS2; in this case, my code is not able to establish the connection to the device and I need to manually change the port.

What is the easier and smarter way to make the code check which is the correct ttyS* port and exit the process if it doesn't find anything?

This is my code:

```
char *portname = "/dev/ttyS4";
int fd;
int wlen;
printf("Opening the connection on serial port\n");
fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
if (fd < 0) {
    printf("Error opening %s: %s\n", portname, strerror(errno));

}
/*baudrate 9600, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit */
set_interface_attribs(fd, B9600);
```

Comment: Use a different udev rule so that the device names get assigned more consistently?  (I don't know enough about udev to say how to do this, though.)

Comment: The buck-passing solution is to take the device name as a command line argument, deferring the intelligence to the code or person who runs the program.  Alternatively, you’ll get have to simulate in code the logic that tells you which terminal the device is connected on.  How do you know what’s right?

Comment: An alternative to a command line argument is a configuration file parameter, if you already use a configuration file.

Comment: The problem is that the program runs with a GUI and the user cannot modify the command line arguments or the configuration file. I was thinking to use a for loop to try to establish a connection with ttyS1, ttyS2 and so on until the connection is done but I think it's a complex solution

Comment: What causes the variability?  In my experience, a serial port is an actual, physical set of pins on a board somewhere, mapped in a 100% predictable, consistent way to a `ttyS` number in the OS.  In your situation does the variability arise because a peripheral device might be connected to a different port, or because a port might be mapped to a different `ttyS` number?  What's WxWidgets, and does the problem have something to do with it?

Comment: the problem is because the device is mapped to a different ttyS number and the same happens with the USB devices. WxWidgets is like GTK libraries, it has nothing to do with the related problem, it was just to give you the whole configuraiton.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet This does sound like a udev problem.  And it's perplexing, because the problem of inconsistent device naming is precisely the problem that udev is intended to *solve*.  You might want to ask a question specifically about udev, and perhaps on the Ubuntu, Unix/Linux, or Server Fault forums.